# Can I use the [ Basic application (Android, Gradle) ] on visual studio 2022 to build a full fledged Android application using c++?

Tags: android, c++, debugging, mobile

Whenever I launch the "create a new project" from visual studio 2022, and hoping to get a good template for Android development using c++, I'm always seeing (Basic application {Android, Gradle}. My question is, can I use this template for a full fledged Android development using c++?. Because I'm confused since I'm seeing the word "Basic application".

I tried loading the template several times but, whenever I try to use Android emulator for debugging, it's not in the debug menu.

Comment: Assuming microsoft did not cripple their flagship IDE on purpose, I'm going to say you missed a step somewhere but impossible to say what. Is your application marked as debuggable in the manifest, for example? Are you starting the app in debug mode from VS?

Comment: Yes, it's set to debug, but it shows no device available on the address bar on debug and run.

Comment: Obvious question the second: did you enable debugger mode on your device? This ought to be covered in the documentation.

Comment: I think it's hard to get it right with the Gradle template for c++ development with Android.. cause I tested if emulator would be available on other templates like the ones for c# and .net, they have the emulator on the debug bar... but for Gradle and Android template, no emulator... always showing can't find device.